# Mixin em LESS para a função "calc()" do CSS, como usar duas variáveis?

Tags: less

Eu tenho este *mixin* que funciona perfeitamente:

```css
.calcW(@valor2: 100px) { 
    width: -o-calc(~"100% - "@valor2);
    width: -webkit-calc(~"100% - "@valor2);
    width: -moz-calc(~"100% - "@valor2);
    width: calc(~"100% - "@valor2);
}
```

Gostaria que no lugar do "100%" do código acima, eu pudesse colocar uma variável chamada `@valor1`, dessa forma eu teria um *mixin* que me ajudaria em todas as situações em que eu precisasse de `calc()`, porém, quando faço da forma abaixo ele não funciona.

```css
.calcW(@valor1: 100%, @valor2: 100px) { 
    width: -o-calc(~"@valor1 - "@valor2);
    width: -webkit-calc(~"@valor1 - "@valor2);
    width: -moz-calc(~"@valor1 - "@valor2);
    width: calc(~"@valor1 - "@valor2);
}
```

Eu já tentei de várias formas, várias combinações, mas nenhum funciona, como posso usar duas variáveis em uma função `calc()`?

Comment: Retire as aspas ("") da variável _@valor1_.

Comment: Foi a primeira maneira que tentei, não funciona.

Pro Less compilar o @calc, ele precisa ser escrito dessa forma:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc

Answer (score 1):

Use [interpolação de variável](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation). Exemplo:

```
.calcW(@valor1: 100%, @valor2: 100px){
   width: calc(~'@{valor1} - ' @valor2)
}
```

ou diretamente:

```
.calcW(@valor1: 100%, @valor2: 100px){
  width: ~'calc(@{valor1} - @{valor2})'
}
```

Comment: Funcionou diretamente apenas, mas somente com os dois pontos após a variavel **@valor1**.

`.calcW(@valor1: 100%, @valor2: 100px){
  width: ~'calc(@{valor1} - @{valor2})'
}`

@renan, muito obrigado!

Comment: @GuilhermeLaureano verdade, erro de sintaxe :D corrigido. A primeira forma é pra funcionar também, deu algum erro?

Comment: Aqui não compilou da primeira vez, mas testei de novo e deu certo, devo ter feito algo errado mas não faço ideia do que, rs.

Então, devo por os prefixos moz e webkit como eu havia feito antes? Se sim, como ficaria a sintaxe?

Comment: Da mesma forma que estava fazendo, a diferença é que usará a interpolação para referenciar a variável `valor1` com a sintaxe `@{}`. Uma parada mais interessante de fazer é definir esses prefixos em uma lista - já que serão sempre os mesmos. E então fazer um *mixin* genérico (que recebe uma propriedade e valor) e percorre a lista aplicando os valores de prefixo à propriedade. Less [suporta loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature). **:D**